# Recursive void function with *& parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, reference, arguments

I have a problem with this recursive void function:

```
void ReadBinaryTree(NODE &p)
{
    char ch;
    File.get(ch);
    if (ch != '#')
    {
        NODE p = new Node;
        p->SetFreq(ch);
        ReadBinaryTree(p->Left());
        ReadBinaryTree(p->Right());
    }
    else return;
}
```

`NODE` is a pointer to the class Node and File is an ifstream object. 
`Left()` and `Right()` return `NODE`.
The compiler does not accept the `p->Left()` and `p->Right()` arguments, the error is:

```
no know conversion for argument 1 from 'NODE {aka Node*} to 'Node *&
```

Could you help me? How can I save the pointers to Node during the recursion?

Comment: Ugh, don't hide pointers behind typedefs!

Comment: @LaszloPapp: It's almost certainly a source of confusion that's making life difficult for the OP here.  Pointers and value types have different syntax and semantics; there's very rarely a case where disguising one as the other is helpful.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) that we can try to compile ourselves (say, in http://ideone.com).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: you really cannot say it ultimately unless you are a style purist.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: I didn't say "ultimately" ;)  What I am saying, though, is that one shouldn't do it unless there's a very good reason to.  It's not a question of style.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: that I agree with, but your initial comment reads like an ultimate exclamation, hence is misleading without further clarification IMHO. Dicussion done, we can move on. ;-)

Comment: [OT]: `else return;` is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `p->Left()` and `p->Right()` are *r-values* and this means you cannot make references of them. The problem arises because `p->Left()` is returning some value (Of type `Node *`), which is being copied into the parameter of `ReadBinaryTree`.

To fix this, your `p->Left()` and `p->Right()` functions should return `NODE &` values (So that your recursion has access to the exact same pointer as is in the parent node, and not just some copy of it).

Also, `NODE p = new Node;` should just be `p = new Node;`.

However, can I suggest that you convert this function into one that returns a value? i.e.

```
NODE ReadBinaryTree(ifstream &File)
{
    char ch; File.get(ch);
    if(ch != '#')
    {
        NODE p = new Node;
        p->setFreq(ch);
        p->Left() = ReadBinaryTree(File);
        p->Right() = ReadBinaryTree(File);

        return p;
    } else return null;
}
```

**This code still needs the left and right accessors to return references.**

**EDIT: Explanation of why references can't take r-values**

`p->Left()` (the accessor function) is returning a **copy** of the left pointer. So while the value is the same as `p->left` (the attribute), the location in memory is different, and importantly, `p->Left()` has been assigned a temporary memory location, because it is an expression, and it was expecting a variable to be 'put into'. Normally, when you pass the expression into a function, it is 'put into' the parameter it is passed in as, **but** if that parameter is a reference, it expects there to already be a non-temporary memory location, which it adopts as its own. So, when you pass an expression (which has a temporary memory location) to something expecting a reference, it complains because it was expecting something with an already fixed memory location, for it to adopt.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! There were 2 serious logical errors! I changed my code as you said and now it works but i don't understand why i need to return a **reference** to the pointer where the address of the child is stored. 

Why when i call the function i pass a simple pointer to Node but in the recursion i need a reference to the pointer?

Comment: Because initially, the `left` and `right` pointers are `null`. Your function needs to *modify the pointer value* so that it points to the new node you constructed. This means you need to have access to the reference of the pointer, and not just a copy of the pointer. Because changing a copy of the pointer in the function would still leave the parent's child nodes pointing to `null`.

Comment: Yes I know, but when the argument is the pointer and the parameter has the "&" operand you are automatically passing the reference to the pointer. Is it true? So I thought I had only to pass the pointer to the child because the parameter is the reference.

Comment: Ah right, yes, I've added an explanation to the end of my answer that hopefully answers your question.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

`cout << Root->Left()->GetKey();`

prints the key of the left child but Left() returns a reference to the pointer! How is it possible? It works in the same way as before!
I think it jumps from an address to another and it's more difficult for the compiler!

Answer (score 2):

**Make it so that `Left` and `Right` return references.** You are trying to pass *temporary values* into `ReadBinaryTree`, which don't bind to the non-`const` reference in the argument list.

**Your recursion is broken anyway**, since inside the function you're operating on a local `NODE p`, not the argument. Maybe you meant `p = new Node;`, though it's hard to tell from this.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadBinaryTree` needs a reference to a pointer, so that it can update the pointer to point to the newly created object. The problem is that `Left()` and `Right()` only returns the address to the child nodes, but not a reference to the pointer where the address is  stored.

So you could change the signature of `Left()` and `Right()` from:

```
NODE Left()
```

to:

```
NODE & Left()
```

As a alternative, you could directly pass the pointers where the child nodes are stored, to `ReadBinaryTree`:

```
ReadBinaryTree (p->left)
```

(This naturally assumes there is a member in `Node` called `left`)

Comment: Why when i call the function i pass a simple pointer to Node but in the recursion i need a reference to the pointer?